# Programming a Discord bot in python- How do make the bot send a random image from a group of images?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my discord bot send a random image from a group of images whenever someone says "dog". Here's what I have:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('dog'):
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(random.choice('dog1.JPG', 'dog2.JPG', 'dog3.JPG')))
```

It doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.choice` takes a sequence of items to choose from as an argument, not the individual items. You need to do `random.choice(('dog1.JPG', 'dog2.JPG', 'dog3.JPG'))`

Comment: It worked, thanks so much!! I'm kinda new to programming, been trying to figure this one out for a while...

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! :) Good luck in your future endeavors!

Comment: Oh okay, didn't know to do that. Thanks.